# Linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to get into C, and I was wondering if I messed up regarding correctly implementing a linked list.

**node.h**

```
typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
}node;
```

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// struct for linked lists
#include "node.h"

bool searchLinked(node* list, int* value);
void insertLinked(node* list, int* value);
void initList(node* list);
void printList(node* list);

/*This small program shows how to utilize the data structure linked lists*/
/*and append, search and delete data in them*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // nodes
    node* root = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // initilize the list and add dummy values
    initList(root);

    // print the list
    printList(root);    

    // search the list for our value, if not found we try to add it
    int value = 1;

    if (!searchLinked(root, &value))
    {
        insertLinked(root, &value);
    }

    free(root);

    return 1;
}

void initList(node* list)
{

    list->n = 4;
    list->next = malloc (sizeof(node));

    // second node access
    list = list->next;

    list->n = 3;
    list->next = malloc (sizeof(node));

    // third node
    list = list->next;

    list->n = 2;

    // set this to NULL since this is last node
    list->next = NULL;

}

// method used to traverse and search our list
bool searchLinked(node* list, int* value)
{

    node* cond = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cond = list;

    while (cond != NULL)
    {
        if (cond->n == *value)
        {   
            free(cond);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cond = cond->next;
        }
    }

    free(cond);
    return false;        
}

void printList (node* list)
{
    node* cond = malloc(sizeof(node));

    cond = list;

    for (int i = 0; cond != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("The root no: %d has the data: %d\n", i, cond->n);
        cond = cond->next;
    }

    free(cond);

}

// this method is used when we want to append data to the last element in the list
// please note that if we were to add it to the start of the list then we would need to
// make sure that we dont drop the list by dissconnecting the 2nd member 
void insertLinked(node* list, int* value)
{
    node* cond = malloc(sizeof(node));
    cond = list;

    while (cond != NULL)
    {
        if (cond->next == NULL)
        {
            // assign the last node the adress of the new node
            cond->next = malloc(sizeof(node));

            // assign the last node to the newly new node
            cond = cond->next;

            // assign the values for the last (new) node
            cond->n = *value;
            cond->next = NULL;

            // try to access the next one, which should be null which will break the loop
            cond = cond->next; 
        }
        else
        {
            cond = cond->next;
        }
    }
free(cond);
}
```

Comment: There's a couple of issues to note with this code (which I'll address in an answer), and your `insertLinked` function actually just adds the node to the end of a heap variable that is destroyed. Did you mean to actually insert the nodes such that they are in sequential order (i.e. `1->2->3->..`), or merely just insert them at the end if the value isn't found?

Comment: `cond = list;` in `insertLinked` leaks the `node` you allocated on the previous line. You probably meant `*cond = *list;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Extra `malloc`s**

Neither `search` nor `print` should be allocating anything. You don't need to - you're just walking the list in both cases, without actually adding anything. You are careful to `free` correctly, but simply deleting all the allocation code would make the functions still work and be even better.

Example for `print`:

```
void printList (node* list)
{
    for (int i = 0; list != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("The root no: %d has the data: %d\n", i, list->n);
        list = list->next;
    }
}
```

I would even move the `list` advancement into the loop statement itself, to make it clear which part is the "body":

```
    for (int i = 0; list != NULL; i++, list = list->next)
    {
        printf("The root no: %d has the data: %d\n", i, list->n);
    }
```

**Leaking memory**

At the end, you:

```
free(root);
```

But you don't `free(root->next)` or `free(root->next->next)`, etc. You should add another function like `deleteList()` or `freeList()` that will `free()` every node in the list.

**inserting**

`insertLinked` *should* `malloc` - but just the one node that you're inserting, you don't need the top-level `malloc` there either. Since we're assuming that the list is non-empty, your logic would be better if you split up the insertion part from the looking-for-the-end part.

Also there is no reason to take the value by pointer:

```
void append(node* list, int value)
{
    while (list->next != NULL) {
        list = list->next;
    }

    // now, list is pointing to the last element, so we just 
    // add a new one
    list->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    list->next->n = value;
    list->next->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Check the return value of `malloc`

If the program runs out of memory, a call to `malloc` can fail.  The indication for this is that the call will return a `NULL` pointer.  You should check for this and avoid dereferencing a `NULL` pointer (which typically causes a program crash).

### Don't allocate memory needlessly

The `printList` routine shouldn't need to allocate memory since all it's supposed to do is iterate over an existing data structure.

```
void printList (const node* list)
{
    for (int i = 0; list != NULL; ++i, list = list->next) {
        printf("Node %d = %d\n", i, list->n);
    }
}
```

The `searchLinked()` routine can be rewritten similarly.

### Use `const` where practical

As shown above, the `printList` routine shouldn't have any reason to modify the list, so this should be indicated and enforced by declaring that parameter `const`:

```
void printList (const node* list)
```

### Use consistent naming

We have `searchLinked()` and `insertLinked()` but `printList()`.  It would be easier to use the code if it had consistent naming.

### Pass simple variables by value

Simple variables such as `int`s and `char` are usually better passed by value than by pointer. It's usually a little bit faster and uses fewer register and memory resources.

### Clean up logic for node insertion

The logic for the `insertLinked()` is not at all clear and once again, the code is pointlessly allocating memory.  Here's a cleaner version:

```
void appendList(node* list, int value)
{
    node* cond = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (cond == NULL) {
        return; // out of memory
    }
    cond->n = value;
    cond->next = NULL;

    // advance to last node
    for (; list && list->next; list = list->next)
    {}
    list->next = cond;
}
```

Also, note that I've changed the name of the function to be more descriptive.

### Don't leak memory

Right now the program leaks memory because the allocated data items in the list are never deleted.  Fix this with a `destroyList()` function that would be called at the end.

### Make the function match the function name

I'd expect a function called `initList` to initialize the list for use and nothing more, but that's not really what it does.  I'd recommend simplifying it like this:

```
void initList(node* list)
{
    list->n = 0;
    list->next = NULL;
}
```

### Use your functions

Now that the `initList` function does only that, within `main`, you can add dummy values by calling your function:

```
initList(root);
appendList(root, 4);
appendList(root, 3);
appendList(root, 2);
```

### Return 0 except for error

Your program peculiarly ends with `return 1` but a nonzero value is typically interpreted by the operating system as an error condition. For that reason, your code should return 0 except on error.  However, since C99, the compiler automatically generates the code corresponding to `return 0` at the end of `main` so there is no need to explicitly write it.